# Python matplotlib: Showing the same figure after plotting progressively more graphs

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, click, point

I want to do something like this, where the figure is the same.

```
fig = plt.figure()

plt.plot(x1,y1)

plt.show()
```

So it'll show a point in figure 1 at x1, y1

Then if I do a mouse click or press a key, something along the lines of:

```
plt.plot(x2,y2)

plt.show()
```

But the figure window shouldn't close, it should just plot a new point on top of it.

I want to do this kinda thing for a math presentation, I know its not even necessary at all but I had this thought and wondered if it was possible for python. I have done MATLAB in the past and stuff like this is so much easier.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to do this is to enable "interactive mode" in matplotlib, which draws automatically on changes.  This is a good way to do thing in the command-line, and is equivalent to how MATLAB does it.  However, it is slower, so it is better not to use it in scripts, so it is not the default:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x1 = 1
x2 = 2

y1 = 1
y2 = 4

plt.ion()  # turn on interactive mode
plt.figure()
plt.xlim(0, 10)  # set the limits so they don't change while plotting
plt.ylim(0, 10)
plt.hold(True)  # turn hold on

plt.plot(x1, y1, 'b.')

input()  # wait for user to press "enter", raw_input() on python 2.x

plt.plot(x2, y2, 'b.')
plt.hold(False)  # turn hold off
```

For a loop, it would work like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

xs = np.arange(10)
ys = np.arange(10)**2

plt.ion()
plt.figure()
plt.xlim(0, 10)
plt.ylim(0, 100)
plt.hold(True)

for x, y in zip(xs, ys):
    plt.plot(x, y, 'b.')
    input()

plt.hold(False)
```

If you use IPython, however, you can just use `%pylab`, which takes care of importing everything and enabling interactive mode:

```
%pylab

xs = arange(10)
ys = arange(10)**2

figure()
xlim(0, 10)  # set the limits so they don't change while plotting
ylim(0, 100)
hold(True)

for x, y in zip(xs, ys):
    plot(x, y, 'b.')
    input()  # raw_input() on python 2.x

hold(False)
```